# Maven project won't compile with Java 8 on OSX

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, java-8

I have the following pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.github.spring-mvc-archetypes</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mvc-quickstart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>maven-archetype</packaging>
        <name>Spring MVC Maven Archetype: Quickstart</name>
  <description>Archetype for creating Spring MVC 4 web application</description>
        <url>https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype</url>
        <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetype</groupId>
        <artifactId>archetype-packaging</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

And the following...

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_05
```

But when I run mvn install I get...

```
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project basic: Compilation failure
[INFO] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[INFO] javac: invalid target release: 1.7
```

Anyone know what I am missing?

**Update**

I found vi src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml  that needed to be updated as well. Now I get...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid target release: 1.8
```

Also I tried this...

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

no dice

Comment: What does running mvn -version output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using JDK 1.8. This issue comes when you are using older version of java and trying to compile with java 8.
Might be you have both versions of java installed and when you are running maven, older version is getting used. Try to print JAVA_HOME that is getting used.

Comment: humm ok let me run java -version when I get home

Answer (score 1):

Works fine with 1.7 and 1.8 source/target.

Please run maven with -X option so you get more information.

My java and maven version:

> mvn -version
>   Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
>   Maven home: /usr/share/maven
>   Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with crappy OSX's crappy Java setup. [This](http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/) helped a lot and `setjdk 1.8.0_05` finished the job thanks guys!